# Is the functionality within Wordpress shortcodes processed, even if they aren't called?

Tags: php, wordpress

For example:
If a plugin gives functionality for 20 shortcodes, but only 5 are utilised throughout the site, are all 20 initiated and therefore take up processing power / time?

Thank you.

Comment: They all get _registered_, but their actual function code will only be executed, when that shortcode gets evaluated anywhere.

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much, this answers my question. I didn't know the correct terminology for "registered".
Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a plugin gives functionality for 20 shortcodes, but only 5 are utilised throughout the site, are all 20 initiated and therefore take up processing power / time?

They all get registered, but their actual function code will only be executed, when that shortcode gets evaluated anywhere.

The “registering” part is basically, that they get added to an array. Then, whenever the parser encounters a short code in the content, it does a look-up in that array, whether a shortcode by that name was registered. If so, the assigned callback function will be executed.